# Chaining Effects on Array of Selectors

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am developing some theme for Wordpress, and I use the following jQuery code:

```
(function ($, root, undefined) {

    $(function () {

        var stepOne = [ "#step1", "#step2", "#step3" ];
        $('#btn').click(getAnimation(stepOne));

    });

})(jQuery);

function getAnimation(getArray) {
    getArray.each(function() {

        var $div = $(this);

        $div.queue('classing', function(next) {
            $div.delay(delay).addClass("stepwalk", next);
        });

        $li.dequeue('classing');

        delay += 250;
    });

}
```

I am facing two problems:

1- Function getAnimation() is being fired without clicking the button #btn.

2- I am having the following error message in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
getAnimation 
(anonymous function) 
j 
k.fireWith 
m.extend.ready
J
```

Comment: Try using `$.each(getArray, function(){ ... });` instead of `getArray.each()`

Comment: Firstly, you're calling the function in the event handler, not referencing it. Secondly you're using the dollarsign outside the closure, where it's not defined as jQuery is in no-conflict mode in Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#btn').click(getAnimation(stepOne));`

This does

1) getAnimation() will be launched with stepOne as parameter

2) it's return value (none => null) will be set as onclick action for #btn

3) Once you click #btn, onclick action will be launched. What we set as onclick action? NULL

Change it to:

`$('#btn').click( function(){getAnimation(stepOne);} );`

Answer (score 0):

It's undefined because it is expecting to store a variable in the click event like you have placed. However, the specific variable type that this event is looking for in it's parenthesis are one's that can be a valid event handler function (i.e. a callback function).

In other words its needs a way to store some functionality for the future when the actual event will be occuring. A `$("#...").click()` method call is a JQuery event handling method call and is telling that DOM object to attach this handler to it for the future. Once a click does occur, the variable is then activated...

This is because the variable is actually meant to store something called a pointer. A pointer is a delegation of a function (behavior for the future) to an event occurence.

Therefore, in order to solve this problem you need to pass in a function call instead like so...

```
$(function () {
    var stepOne = [ "#step1", "#step2", "#step3" ];
    $('#btn').click( function() { getAnimation(stepOne) });

});
```